# VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT VkAccessFlags set to 0?

Tags: vulkan

In the Vulkan spec it defines:

> `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT` is equivalent to `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` **with
> `VkAccessFlags` set to 0** when specified in the second synchronization scope, but specifies no
> stages in the first scope.

and similarly:

> `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` is equivalent to `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` **with
> `VkAccessFlags` set to 0** when specified in the first synchronization scope, but specifies no stages
> in the second scope.

I'm unclear what it means by "with `VkAccessFlags` set to 0" in this context?

Technically `VkAccessFlags` is a type, not a variable, so it can't be set to anything.

(It seems to be adjusting the definitions of `TOP/BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` for some special property of `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` with respect to `VkAccessFlags`, but I can't quite see what that special property is or where it is specified.)

Anyone know what it's talking about?

(or, put another way:  If we removed those two utterances of "with `VkAccessFlags` set to 0" from the spec, what would break?)

Answer (score 3):

It is roundabout way to say the interpretation of the stage flag is different for a memory dependency.

For execution dependency in `src` it takes the stage bits you provide, and logically-earlier stages are included automatically. Similarly for `dst`, logically-later stages are included automatically.

But this applies only to the execution dependency. For a memory dependency, only the stage flags you provide count (and none are added automatically).

For example, let's say you have `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` + `VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT` in `src`. That means all memory writes from all previous commands will be *made available*. But if you have `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` + `VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT` in `src`, that means all memory writes from only `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` stage are *made available*, so no memory writes are made available (because that particular stage doesn't make any).

Either way IMO, for code clarity it is better to always state all pipeline stages explicitly whenever one can.